# Using Perl to wait for a file to enter a folder and move it to a different location

Tags: perl, file, wait

I am rather new to Perl and would like to seek some advise on how to use Perl to detect if a files have populated a folder and then to move those files to a different location.

I have seen many codes that take about waiting for a specific file but my company uses a number randomizer for the files, so no two files have the same name.

Appreciate any help in this matter.

Thanks again.

Aaron

Comment: What platform do you want to do this on, it might influence the answer? Windows, Linux, OS X etc

Comment: Hello, I am using this on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: How do you know that the other process has finished writing the file before moving?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: @daxim suggests in the comments that [File::ChangeNotify](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/File-ChangeNotify-0.22/lib/File/ChangeNotify.pm) is a cross platform module which works in a very similar manner to Win32::FileSystem::Watcher.

A quick search of [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) suggests [Win32::FileSystem::Watcher](http://search.cpan.org/~ank/Win32-FileSystem-Watcher-0.1.0/lib/Win32/FileSystem/Watcher.pm) can alert you to changes in a directory.  You'll need to install this module and any dependencies.

From the documentation:

```
use Win32::FileSystem::Watcher;

my $watcher = Win32::FileSystem::Watcher->new( "c:\\" );

# or

my $watcher = Win32::FileSystem::Watcher->new(
    "c:\\",
    notify_filter  => FILE_NOTIFY_ALL,
    watch_sub_tree => 1,
);

$watcher->start();
print "Monitoring started.";

sleep(5);

# Get a list of changes since start().
my @entries = $watcher->get_results();

# Get a list of changes since the last get_results()
@entries = $watcher->get_results();

# ... repeat as needed ...

$watcher->stop(); # or undef $watcher

foreach my $entry (@entries) {
    print $entry->action_name . " " . $entry->file_name . "\n";
}

# Restart monitoring

# $watcher->start();
# ...
# $watcher->stop();
```

Comment: The cross-platform module is [File::ChangeNotify](http://p3rl.org/File::ChangeNotify).